# Error when using AssetManager to open assets file

Tags: android

I am trying to open an assets file in my Android app. When I try to use the following code to do that I get the error message `Cannot resolve method 'getBaseContext()'`. First I tried to do it with just `getAssets()` instead of `getBaseContext().getAssets()` which displayed the error message `Cannot resolve method 'getAssets()'`. I also tried to `clean` and `rebuild` the project but it did not change anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
try {
    AssetManager assetManager = getBaseContext().getAssets();
    InputStream is = assetManager.open("MAIN.sql");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `YourClass.this.getBaseContext()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of **getBaseContext()** , try creating a class level variable **Context** at the top like this:

```
Context mContext = YourActivityName.this;
```

and then use this variable to get the assets

```
mContext.getAssets();
```

If you are trying to do this on a **NON Activity** class, like a class you created separately not relating any activity you will have to receive the activity context as a parameter so when you instance your class you send the context like this

```
YourAssetClass assetClass = new YourAssetClass(mContext)
assetClass.getAssets();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked! It was a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper` so context was already a parameter of the constructor of it but I used it in a method that I did  not call directly so I just saved the context in a variable `context` in the class and then used `AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();`.